# Arimax forecasting

Tags: r, prediction, arima

I need to forecast sales on daily basis using arima model with independent variables as weekdays.

So i build up the model :
d= data,
Total = sales Monday,tuesday...Sunday are my independent Vars
i am using library(forecast)

```
'fit=arima(d$Total,xreg=cbind(Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday),order=c(1,1,1))'
```

Please help me to proceed further and to predict future values.

How to decide p,d,q and to plot forecasted Vs Actual Values ? please help

Comment: 'predict(fit)' from base or 'forecast(fit)' from 'forecast' package.

Comment: better use 'auto.arima()' from 'forecast' package

Comment: Error in predict.Arima(object, n.ahead = h) : 
  'xreg' and 'newxreg' have different numbers of columns - when i use forecast(fit)

Comment: Arima modelling works on a time series object 'ts()'. Please do some reading on ARIMA modelling in R before modelling.

Comment: Sir Can you guide me on my first question.to identify p,d,q?.. or any links which i can refer

Comment: it depends on the PACF and ACF values. As far as I know auto.arima(), optimizes it automatically. https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/12/complete-tutorial-time-series-modeling/ this is a good place to start on ARIMA forecasting.